# remove() method in hashTable array

Tags: java, arrays, key, hashtable

so I'm doing this assignment, and for some reason the remove() method which removes the key from the dictionary, doesn't work properly. Here are my methods:

```
public boolean find(String key){
    // Returns true if dictionary has the specified key and false otherwise
    OpsCount++;
    int FoundIndex = 0; // have to reset it for each find() call
    int index = MADcomp(key); // get the location of the element we're looking for
    int c = 0; // counter

    while (size > c){
        String e = D[index]; // gets the entry of the location of our element
            if (e == null){
                return false;
            }
            else if (e != AVAILABLE){ // if not a removed element
                if (e.equals(key)){ //if the element in that cell has the same key as the element
                                    //we're looking for
                    FoundIndex = index;
                    return true;
                }       
            }
            ProbesCount++;
            index = (index + 1) % size; // goes to next cell
            System.out.println("new index " + index);
            c++;
    }
    return false; // nothing found

}
public void remove(String key) throws DictionaryException{
    OpsCount++;
    boolean found = find(key); //we're calling the find method and we'll have the indexOfFound
                               //variable updated for this element
    if (found == true){
        D[FoundIndex] = AVAILABLE;
        //System.out.println(D[FoundIndex]);

        n--;
    }
     else{

        throw new DictionaryException("No entry with this key exists.");
     }

}
```

And my test method.

```
// Test 4: try to delete a nonexistent entry.
// Should throw an exception.
try {
    h.remove("R6C8");
    System.out.println("***Test 4 failed");
} catch (DictionaryException e) {
    System.out.println("   Test 4 succeeded");
}

// Test 5: delete an actual entry.
// Should not throw an exception.
try {
    h.remove( "R3C1");
        if (!h.find("R3C1"))
         System.out.println("   Test 5 succeeded");
        else  System.out.println("***Test 5 failed");
} catch (DictionaryException e) {
    System.out.println("***Test 5 failed");
}
```

I get that test 4 succeeds, but 5 fails, and the program doesn't terminate. I also checked that R3C1 becomes AVAILABLE (array to which I put removed entries). It fails, because it finds R3C1 again, i.e. if I say

```
if (h.find("R3C1"))
             System.out.println("   Test 5 succeeded");
```

it succeeds.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're redeclaring foundIndex here:

```
int FoundIndex = 0; // have to reset it for each find() call
```

That shadows the FoundIndex from the class. So your function never sets the FoundIndex used by remove,

Try changing that line to:

```
FoundIndex=0;
```

See:
http://blog.sanaulla.info/2008/06/27/shadowing-variables-in-java-demystified/

Comment: Thank you!! spent so much time trying to find the mistake lol